# How to properly use JSON.parse?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm receiving a string with php and then parsing it:

String saved in db:

```
{"totale_casi":825,"terapia_intensiva":24,"ricoverati_con_sintomi":122,"totale_ospedalizzati":146,"isolamento_domiciliare":598,"totale_positivi":744,"dimessi_guariti":40,"deceduti":41,"tamponi":6477}, {"totale_casi"235,"terapia_intensiva":123,"ricoverati_con_sintomi":154,"totale_ospedalizzati":344,"isolamento_domiciliare":654,"totale_positivi":786,"dimessi_guariti":988,"deceduti":675,"tamponi":2324}
```

Then I do

```
var myJson = '<?php echo $dataCustom; ?>';
```

This is how It prints on js

```
var myJson = '{"totale_casi":825,"terapia_intensiva":24,"ricoverati_con_sintomi":122,"totale_ospedalizzati":146,"isolamento_domiciliare":598,"totale_positivi":744,"dimessi_guariti":40,"deceduti":41,"tamponi":6477}, {"totale_casi"235,"terapia_intensiva":123,"ricoverati_con_sintomi":154,"totale_ospedalizzati":344,"isolamento_domiciliare":654,"totale_positivi":786,"dimessi_guariti":988,"deceduti":675,"tamponi":2324}';
```

How to read a property?

Tried

```
var myJson = '<?php echo $dataCustom; ?>';
var customJsonData = JSON.parse(myJson);
```

I am trying to:

```
for(var d = 0; d < customJsonData.length; ++d) {
  console.log(customJsonData[d]totale_positivi);
}
```

**UPDATE**

This is how I am constructing the json

```
var saveJsondata = {
    "totale_casi": totCasiRegione,
    "terapia_intensiva": totTerapiaRegione,
    "ricoverati_con_sintomi": totSintomiRegione,
    "totale_ospedalizzati": totOspedalizzatiRegione,
    "isolamento_domiciliare": totDomiciliariRegione,
    "totale_positivi": totPositiviRegione,
    "dimessi_guariti": totGuaritiRegione,
    "deceduti": totDecedutiRegione,
    "tamponi": totTamponiRegione
};
```

Then sending that to db via ajax and Adding `|` in order to have something that I can use to separate the objects later. I am saving `saveJsondata` to a field called `jsonBlock`

Then in php I do:

```
$dataSavedBlocks = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'jsonBlock');
$dataCustom = $dataSavedBlocks[0]; 
$dataCustom = str_replace('|', '', $dataCustom);
```

Finally in js:

```
var myJson = '<?php echo $dataCustom; ?>';
```

Output of that is:

```
var myJson = {"totale_casi":825,"terapia_intensiva":24,"ricoverati_con_sintomi":122,"totale_ospedalizzati":146,"isolamento_domiciliare":598,"totale_positivi":744,"dimessi_guariti":40,"deceduti":41,"tamponi":6477}  ,{"totale_casi":47348,"terapia_intensiva":1362,"ricoverati_con_sintomi":11726,"totale_ospedalizzati":13088,"isolamento_domiciliare":12935,"totale_positivi":26023,"dimessi_guariti":13020,"deceduti":8305,"tamponi":133588}  ;
```

Now I need to loop and get each individual value

Comment: Embed it like this instead: `var myJson = <?php echo json_encode($dataCustom); ?>;`

Comment: @zerkms ok let me try it

Comment: It won't solve your original problem though, it's just to embed a literal properly in your JS.

Comment: You don'g have an array, so nothing to iterate: just `customJsonData.totale_positivi`

Comment: @zerkms ok so why did you suggest me that?

Comment: "to embed a literal properly in your JS" -- I have shown you how to do that _properly_, your current solution is error prone.

Comment: @zerkms right, how can i resolve it if you may?

Comment: I have already left a comment how you access data: please read everything more carefully `customJsonData.totale_positivi`

Comment: @zerkms I am reading it and testing each time. I have now added another set of data and maybe it is clearer

Comment: you provided something comma separated. What does it mean? It's not a valid JSON anymore

Comment: @zerkms exactly. Give me the time to understand your suggestions, I now need to add `[ ]` but do give me sometime, I'm not here to waste our time. And the down votes are for? Not know what it is there and I am asking help so that I can first learn, then resolve? Please hang on a sec.

Comment: @zerkms I have updated the question

Comment: @zerkms I have resolved it and posted my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved it:

```
var myJson = '<?php echo $dataCustom; ?>';
var customJsonData = JSON.parse("["+myJson+"]");
```

Now that we have a valid json, we can loop and iterate with each obj:

```
for(var d = 0; d < customJsonData.length; ++d) {
  console.log(customJsonData[d].totale_casi);
}
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out. If you want to log all the keys and values in each object you can use `customJsonData.forEach((obj) => {
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
       console.log(key, value)
    })
})`

Comment: @Ramesh thanks a lot, I will have to learn how to not use for loop

Comment: There's nothing wrong with how you're using it. I just wanted to let you know that using `Object.entries` will help you if you want both keys and values easily.

Comment: @Ramesh yes but if I knew how to use it, then I would avoid this lots of code. See this code review question I've asked before https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/239942/better-way-to-get-total-of-different-items-in-loop

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the loop... just try console.log(customJsonData.totale_positivi). JSON properties become object attributes when parsed. Hence JavaScript *Object* Notation   8^D

Comment: what if we have 2 sets?

Comment: "Hence JavaScript Object Notation" --- that was a terrible name in the beginning. Ideally one does not link JSON and JS at all.

Comment: @rob.m if you have an array - you iterate over it. In your question you don't though.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is not an Array. If you want to iterate, use object keys.

```js
var myJson = '{"totale_casi":825,"terapia_intensiva":24,"ricoverati_con_sintomi":122,"totale_ospedalizzati":146,"isolamento_domiciliare":598,"totale_positivi":744,"dimessi_guariti":40,"deceduti":41,"tamponi":6477}  ';
var customJsonData = JSON.parse(myJson);
Object.keys(customJsonData).forEach(key=>{
  console.log(customJsonData[key]);
})
```

If you want a single value:

```js
var myJson = '{"totale_casi":825,"terapia_intensiva":24,"ricoverati_con_sintomi":122,"totale_ospedalizzati":146,"isolamento_domiciliare":598,"totale_positivi":744,"dimessi_guariti":40,"deceduti":41,"tamponi":6477}  ';
var customJsonData = JSON.parse(myJson);
console.log(customJsonData.terapia_intensiva)
```

If you have an array of objects :

```js
var myJson = '[{"totale_casi":825,"terapia_intensiva":24,"ricoverati_con_sintomi":122,"totale_ospedalizzati":146,"isolamento_domiciliare":598,"totale_positivi":744,"dimessi_guariti":40,"deceduti":41,"tamponi":6477},{"totale_casi":826,"terapia_intensiva":24,"ricoverati_con_sintomi":122,"totale_ospedalizzati":146,"isolamento_domiciliare":598,"totale_positivi":744,"dimessi_guariti":40,"deceduti":41,"tamponi":6477},{"totale_casi":827,"terapia_intensiva":24,"ricoverati_con_sintomi":122,"totale_ospedalizzati":146,"isolamento_domiciliare":598,"totale_positivi":744,"dimessi_guariti":40,"deceduti":41,"tamponi":6477}]';
    var customJsonData = JSON.parse(myJson);
    customJsonData.forEach(data=>{
        console.log(data.totale_casi);
    })
```

Comment: how to get `terapia_intensiva` value only? I mean each single value separated and what if We had 2 sets or more?

Comment: @rob.m That's invalid JSON

Comment: @Ramesh indeed, just finding it out, will update the question. need to addd [

Comment: @rob.m Okay, can you also add how `myJson` looks like after `var myJson = '<?php echo $dataCustom; ?>';`

Comment: @Ramesh yes sure, I just did it and updated the question. thanks a lot

Comment: @Ramesh I have resolved it and posted my own answer. Thanks a lot